# Búsqueda Vi/Vim linux

Tags: linux, terminal, vim

El problema que tengo en vi es que accidentalmente presioné [shift + #] y ahora la palabra donde estaba el cursor está resaltada. Tengo entendido que es una búsqueda, pero ahora no sé como hacer para que regrese a como estaba (sin color resaltado).

El resaltado permanece en la palabra para cualquier cosa que abra en Vi.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el modo "normal" puedes hacer:

```
:noh
```

O bien limpiar la última búsqueda

```
:let @/ = ""
```